# Error: Unable to find a match: java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel tomcat

Tags: dockerfile

i am getting error while running docker file

Sending build context to Docker daemon   26.8MB
Step 1/6 : FROM amazonlinux:latest
---> d027b21cae33
Step 2/6 : RUN yum -y install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel tomcat
---> Running in 013653e18b59
Amazon Linux 2023 repository                    9.1 MB/s |  14 MB     00:01
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:03 ago on Tue Jun 13 16:17:37 2023.
No match for argument: java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
No match for argument: tomcat
**Error: Unable to find a match: java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel tomcat
The command '/bin/sh -c yum -y install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel tomcat' returned a non-zero code: 1**

my dockerfile look like..

## Use the Amazon Linux base image

FROM amazonlinux:latest

## Install Java and Tomcat

RUN yum -y install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel tomcat

## Copy the web application files

COPY jenkins.war /usr/share/tomcat/webapps/

## Set the working directory

WORKDIR /usr/share/tomcat

## Expose the Tomcat port

EXPOSE 8082

## Start Tomcat

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]

i am unable to troubleshoot